# Positive semi-definiteness of correlation matrix

Tags: statistics

I know how to prove positive-semidefinateness for a covariance matrix, but am a little stumped as to how to do the same thing for a correlation matrix

Can anybody give me a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Wikipedia article on the Covariance matrix, the Correlation matrix is defined as
$$\text{Corr}(\textbf{X}) = \textbf{D}\Sigma\textbf{D},$$
where $\textbf{D}=(\text{diag}(\Sigma))^{-1/2}$. Hence for any vector $\textbf{v}$ of appropriate dimension,
$$\textbf{v}^{T}\textbf{D}\Sigma\textbf{D}\textbf{v} = \textbf{w}^{T}\Sigma\textbf{w},$$
where $\textbf{w} = \textbf{D}\textbf{v}.$ But ...

Comment: Well I know if the above is non-negative, then I have my result. But the problem is that matrix in between the w=Dv

Comment: $\Sigma$ is the Covariance matrix.

Comment: I'm sorry. I am still stuck as to how to proceed from here.

Comment: As $\Sigma$ is the Covariance matrix, as you say above, it is positive semidefinite. Therefore for any vector $\textbf{u}$, $\textbf{u}^{T}\Sigma\textbf{u}\geq 0$. In particular, for $\textbf{u}=\textbf{w}$.